# Charging a 4.4v lithium polymer battery with 5v?

Tags: integrated-circuit, battery-charging, lithium-ion, charger, lithium-polymer

Can anybody tell me how can i charge a 4.4v lithium poly. battery. I have a tp4056 charging circuit, but the problem is that it stops charging at 4.2v. I have searched on Ali but haven't found any 4.4 v charging module.This battery is from a MI power bank but its circuit got faulty so i am thinking of using it with a specialized circuit.[image: lithium polymer battery 10000mah]

Comment: So just charge it to 4.2V. Safer, and the battery will have longer cycle life.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a custom charger BUT I'd strongly recommend against it.

The energy difference between 4.2 & 4.4V will be small and you will get useful whole of life capacity improvement by using 4.2V end of charge.

You can test this by

- CAREFULLY manually charging to 4.4V with a power supply set to 4.4V and current limited to Imax,
- then letting the current drop in CV (=4.4V mode) to say Imax/2
- THEN discharging to 4.2V - ideally at constant current but a fixed R would do.

See how long that takes, which will give you an idea of the energy / mAh in the 4.2 - 4.4 V area. It will not be vast compared to whole battery capacity.

The TP4056 should do a good job

Comment: Sir but there's a problem with the tp4056 module that when i discharge the battery through its (tp4056) inbuilt protection circuit it stops the charging at 3.7v but the battery nominal voltage is 3.85v which i think may damage the battery in the longer run

Comment: @DineshBhardwaj I think the figures in your comment are probably wrong. A TP4056 module should NOT stop discarge at 3.7V. Maybe at 2.7V. | 3.85V is the average voltage of your battery and is not the Vmin or Vmax.